# Chatting app on flask(one to one implementation)

Tags: javascript, python, flask-socketio

I am trying to build a flask app in which users can chat in group as well as each other. in order to implement this i am using flaskSocketio. I am able to broadcast my message but how can i do one to one chat....between different users
I have database of users registered to me.......

```
@app.route("/chat/")
def chatting():
 return render_template('chatHome.html')


@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(msg):
 send(msg, broadcast=True, include_self=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=(int)(os.environ.get('PORT', 7001)), 
                  debug=True)


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on('message', function(msg) {
    $("#messages").append('<p style="padding: 10px; background-color: hotpink; 
    overflow: auto;">'+msg+'</p>');
    console.log('Received message');
});
$('#sendbutton').on('click', function() {
    socket.send($('#myMessage').val());
    $("#rightsend").append('<p style="padding: 10px; background-color: 
#2aabd2;  overflow: auto;">'+($('#myMessage').val())+'</p>');
    $('#myMessage').val('');
});

$("#myMessage").keyup(function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13){
    $("#sendbutton").click();
}
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Here is an example project that uses Flask and Flask-SocketIO to create a simple chat service. https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO-Chat There's also a blog post that explains how it works, https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent

Answer (score 1):

Each user gets assigned a session ID or `sid` when they connect. You can access the `sid` assigned to a client as `request.sid` in any event handler for that client. What people typically do is associate the `sid` given to a client to the actual user in the connect event handler.

Once you have a way to find the `sid` currently associated with a user, the server can send a message just to that user by adding a `room=sid` argument to the `emit()` call.